# How to turn on the typographic layout in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus, special-characters

I tried many things but to no avail (I added 'lv3:ralt_switch', 'misc:typo' to ’input-sources’ using dconf-editor). So how do I set up the 3rg and 4th level of the keyboard? I use En, Ru and Uk layouts + iBus for Sanskrit and Bengali. When I had MATE I also had troubles with setting it until I checked Miscellaneous Compatibility Options → Enable extra typographic characters. But in Xubuntu there is no such menu :(

Comment: It would probably help if you edited your question and gave us an example for one specific keyboard layout and told us exactly which character(s) are difficult to type.

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question so that it is more clear. I says it all. On my previous MATE machine I had a need to type "[" and "]" on Russian layout without switching to English just to type two characters and then switching back to Ru to continue typing. Another one is "...". Another one is "|". So in MATE I just edited "input-sources" in dconf-editor and checked "Enable extra typographic characters" and that was it. In Xubuntu I can't get that to work. So I don't think that English (US) don't include 3rd level symbols. In MATE it worked like a charm without any additional workaround.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some keyboard layouts include 3rd and 4th level symbols, some don't. Those which do, such as the Ukrainian layout, enable the `lv3:ralt_switch` option automatically, so normally that's not necessary to set manually via dconf (or gsettings).

The English (US) and the basic Russian layouts don't include 3rd and 4th level symbols.

AFAIK, the xkb-option `lv3:ralt_switch` does not apply when using IBus input methods.

*Edit:*

One way to enable extra typographic characters system wide is to open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and make sure it includes the line:

```
XKBOPTIONS=misc:typo
```

Hopefully that makes a difference at next reboot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I have exactly the same layouts and iBus on a MATE machine and it works perfectly well with ralt_switch. So I believe it should be possible in XFCE too? It didn't work until I checked the box specified above.

Comment: @brijabasi: I didn't mean to say that IBus wouldn't work if `lv3:ralt_switch` is enabled, but probably the IBus input methods don't make use of it.